# only read n rows from scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I am working with scipy sparse matrices. I only need small subsample of the whole matrice (n first rows). Is there a way to read only the first n_rows of a npz file ?

Below is an exemple of what I am currently doing:

```
n = 1000
X = scipy.sparse.load_npz('X.npz')
X = X[:n,:]
```

Comment: What you are doing is the only way.  You can read the code for `load_npz` for yourself.

Comment: The `npz` format saves the attribute arrays of the matric to a zip archive (`data`, `indices`, `indptr` for `csr`).  The load reads those arrays and makes a new sparse matrix.  I suppose someone who understands the `csr` format could make a matrix from just a portion of those arrays (but they still have to loaded in full).

Comment: Given the usage of a dict for save, it seems difficult to change the behavior of load without changing save before ...

Comment: In memory, a sparse array is an object with several array attributes (depending on the format).  Indexing as in `X[:n,:]` makes a new sparse matrix from the attributes of the original.  A sparse matrix is not a subclass of `numpy.ndarray`.  Even with dense `ndarray`, the only ways to perform a partial load are to load in `mmap_mode`, or save and load via `h5py`.